# Process Hierarchy in Windows

Tags: windows, unix, process

Like Unix based operating system, why is there no process hierarchy in Windows? Is there a reason for it or is it just a choice? How does the processes work in windows then?

Comment: Because there's no need for one?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the necro thread but there is no answer. There is a process hierarchy in Windows. You can't see it from the Task manager but with SysInternal ProcessExplorer you see it all up to the kernel components. You can also easily retrieve that information with various winapi calls.